# Schrodinger eqn with 'rescaled' Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If $U_t$ (time evolution operator) is the solution to the following Schrodinger equation for a time dependent finite dimentional quantum system:

$\frac{d U_t}{dt} = -i H_t U_t$

can the solution to the new Schrodinger equation:

$\frac{d U'_t}{dt} = - i f(t) H_t U'_t$

be expressed simply in terms of the previous solution $U_t$? Here $f(t)$ is some, not too wild, real scalar function.

Comment: what does $H_t$ stand for? Hamiltonian operator is usually two-dimentional, e.g. includes time and coordinate

Comment: The system is finite dim. there is no position coordinate. $H_t$ is simply a time dependent hermitian matrix.